# How can AWS determine target when an Internet address conflicts with an VPC inner address

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

For example: 
Your VPC CIDR is 10.0.0.0/16
you have those router tables:

10.0.0.0/16   target: local
0.0.0.0/0     target: MyInternetGateway

You have a EC2 instance with IP address **10.0.3.20**

Now you tried to connect an internet address **10.0.3.20**, how does AWS connect to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer:

Some IPv4 and IPV6 address ranges are reserved for special purpose:

[Reserved_IP_addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses)

For example:

10.0.0.0/8 is reserved for private network.

So there are no internet address used 10.0.0.0/8.

So you could not get an address conflict if you follow the reservation rules.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks!  This is most correct answer. Looks like a lot of people didn't understand my question.

Answer (score 3):

AWS uses the most specific matching for the routes as it is logical to route the traffic to a specific route if available before letting it go in the wild with wider routing rule like `0.0.0.0`.

> If your route table has multiple routes, we use the most specific route that matches the traffic (longest prefix match) to determine how to route the traffic.

Source: [Route Tables - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html)

So in your scenario IP address `10.0.3.20` will be routed using the most specific matching, which is

```
10.0.0.0/16 target: local
```